# Nginx redirect last fragment in string

Tags: nginx

I'm struggling to get my head around how to rewrite the following url:

http://example.com/blog/01-01-01/string

to

http://example.com/string

The following regex matches the string - `^blog\/\d*-\d*-\d*\/(.*)`

My nginx config block is:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
  proxy_redirect off;
  rewrite ^blog\/\d*-\d*-\d*\/(.*) http://example/$1 permanent;
}
```

however this does not work. I'm struggling to see what I'm missing here. I've tried a few variations of this but I'm stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
rewrite  ^/blog/\d+-\d+-\d+/(.*)  /$1  redirect;
```

Or, a supposedly slightly more efficient way to do the very same:

```
rewrite  ^/blog/\d+-\d+-\d+(/.*)  $1  redirect;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`^/blog/[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]\/[A-Za-z\-]*$`

Really depends on how specific that URL is going to be.

Comment: ah that stripped the blog part of the url but not the date.

Comment: Edited the regex